# How to insert a word in each column of a multicolumn text file?

Tags: awk

My multicolumn text file looks like this

```
A_hdr    B_hdr   C_hdr    D_hdr     E_hdr 
Ep       Ep      Ep       Ep        Ep             
r16f     r42f    r42f     r17f-03   r42f    
r52f     r14f    r14f     r44f-04   r18f   
r51f     r44f    r44f     r13f-03   r10f   
r42f     r13f    r13f     r45f-03   r14f    
r13f     r47f    r47f     r14f-04   r44f
```

I want to add a word "Ot" as a first element in of each of the columns. And my desired output is like this

```
A_hdr    B_hdr   C_hdr    D_hdr     E_hdr 
Ot       Ot      Ot       Ot        Ot
Ep       Ep      Ep       Ep        Ep             
r16f     r42f    r42f     r17f-03   r42f    
r52f     r14f    r14f     r44f-04   r18f   
r51f     r44f    r44f     r13f-03   r10f   
r42f     r13f    r13f     r45f-03   r14f    
r13f     r47f    r47f     r14f-04   r44f
```

Comment: anything you tried and didn't work?  Since you're very specific with the language, you might have some idea?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '1; NR==1{gsub(/\S+/,"0t"); print}' file | column -t
A_hdr  B_hdr  C_hdr  D_hdr    E_hdr
0t     0t     0t     0t       0t
Ep     Ep     Ep     Ep       Ep
r16f   r42f   r42f   r17f-03  r42f
r52f   r14f   r14f   r44f-04  r18f
r51f   r44f   r44f   r13f-03  r10f
r42f   r13f   r13f   r45f-03  r14f
r13f   r47f   r47f   r14f-04  r44f
```

If you're not using GNU awk than change `\S` to `[^[:space:]]`

Comment: Can you please explain the reason of putting 1 in the beginning of AWK? And Why NR==1 is not considering header rather than 2nd row. Thanks

Comment: `1` is a common awk idiom for printing the current line by providing a true condition. `NR==1` **IS** the header line - I'm changing it after printing it and then printing it, now modified, a second time.